# Flask application and azure functions

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-functions

I want to try my flask application with azure functions:

Here is my code:

```
Flask_App = Flask(__name__)
api=Api(Flask_App)

@Flask_App.route('/')
def index():
    """Displays the index page accessible ate '/' """

    return render_template('index.html')

# @Flask_App.route('/operation_result/', methods=['POST'])
@Flask_App.route('/operation_result')
def operation_result():
    some code

    
    
        return render_template ('index.html', input=input , operation=operation, result= result, calculation_success=True)
    
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return render_template ('index.html', input=input, operation=operation, result= "Bad input", calculation_success=False, error= "You cannot calculate by 0")

    except ValueError:
        return render_template ('index.html', input=input, operation=operation, result= "Bad input", calculation_success=False, error= "Cannot perform operations with provided input")




def main(req: func.HttpRequest,context:func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return AzureFunctionsWsgi(Flask_App).main(req)
```

However, I still get: "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again"

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hi Sofia, what line does the error occur in, can you include traceback?

Comment: Hi @BijayRegmi I don't get any error, in the vs code, I only get url not found when I try to acess it.

Comment: are you trying to access `http://localhost:port/` and `http://localhost:port/operation_result` ?

Comment: trying to access `operation_result/index.html` will fail because `index.html` is only being rendered in flask app internally.

Comment: sorry, but how did you acess operation_result/index.html to see the error?

Comment: I assumed that is how you were trying to access, I did not access anything because you have not disclosed anything about server details

Comment: I am trying to acess with this way: http://localhost:7071/api/Flask_App/{*route}

Comment: why dont you try `http://localhost:7071/` and  `http://localhost:7071/operation_result/`

Comment: I tried http://localhost:7071/, but then I get redirected to azure functions microsoft page

Comment: and that is not what `index.html` was supposed to do? That seems to have solved the first problem anyhow.

Comment: No, because it should appear the functionallity of the flask app